# How can I remove only the last single character not the entire value?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

how to remove last character from tvalue? e.g: value was for tvalue= "001 212 777 3456"

now when keyboard('BACKSPACE') is called it should not clear entirely but only delete one character at the end, instead of entire.

```
function keyboard(input) {
  if (input==='BACKSPACE') {
    tvalue = '';
  } else if(input ==='QUOTE') {
    tvalue = tvalue + "'";
  } else if(input ==='SPACE') {
    tvalue = tvalue + " ";
  } else {
    tvalue = tvalue + input;
  }    
  $('#' + tinput).val(tvalue).trigger('input');

  console.log(">>> Keyboard: ", input);
}
keyboard('BACKSPACE');
console.log('Show me the input now? ' , tvalue);
```

Expected output is:

```
 001 212 777 345
 001 212 777 34
 001 212 777 3
 001 212 777 
 001 212 777
 001 212 77
```

Expected output is "Not empty completely but only the last one character".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for substring?

```
tvalue.substring(0,(tvalue.length - 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as easy as

```
tvalue = tvalue.slice (0, -1);
```

It basically chops off the last character, exactly what you want.